# Why in this call to AfxWinInit I get a warning C6309?

Tags: c++, warnings, static-analysis

while doing some static code analysis I've found a weird one. On a call like this one:

```
if(!AfxWinInit(moduleHandle,NULL,::GetCommandLine(),0)
```

I get the warning C6309 at the second parameter (C6309: argument 2 is null: it does not adhere to function specification of AfxWinInit)

Docs say that for Win32 applications the second parameter must be NULL so the questions is:

a) What's wrong, my code, the AfxWinInit declaration or the static code analysis?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    friend BOOL AFXAPI AfxWinInit(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
            _In_z_ LPTSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow);
```

That looks wrong to me, the 2nd argument should have been annotated as `_In_opt_`.  From the [SAL Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx) documentation:

**Optional Option**
Describes if the buffer itself is optional. These annotations can be applied to values in the Parameters layer, Return Value layer, or Pre / Post layer.

- (none) 
  The pointer to the buffer must not be NULL.
- opt_ 
  The pointer to the buffer might be NULL. It will be checked before being dereferenced.